# How to get the creator of a channel on event channelCreate in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Would it be possible to find the creator of a channel when the channelCreate event triggers? I've tried looking at the documentation of channels & channelCreate and to log the channel object to my console but there doesn't seem to be a parameter that clearly states "This ID created the channel". I know it has to be somewhere since Discord uses it in the audit logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try listening to the `channelCreate` event and then fetch the [GuildAuditLogs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogs) with [`Guild.fetchAuditLogs()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs). Then you can look for the most recent AuditLogEntry who's [AuditLogAction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AuditLogAction) is `CHANNEL_CREATE`. From that you can get the [`.executor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=executor) to see who triggered the event

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get the channelCreator of an command, ex:

!channelcreate

you just need to get the author of the message.

else idk

Comment: try message.author.tag

Comment: The event always triggers, not just when someone uses a command to create a channel. Also, my bot doesn't have a command that creates a channel. I'm just looking how to get the creator of the channel when the event channelCreate triggers (so whenever someone makes a channel, whatever channel it is). No need for me to post my code, as it's in a client.on('channelCreate') block. There's nothing else to it.

Comment: you can make

client.on('channelCreate', async (ch) => {
console.log(ch.author.tag)
})