# discord.js V12 - Console commands, and variable output showing as Undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I am new to JavaScript. I am making a Discord bot because it's the only thing I would really use JavaScript for at the moment and I want to learn something. Whenever I try to show something like an id it says undefined.

```
    client.on("channelCreate", function(channel){
    console.log(channel.type+` channel, `+channel.name+`, was created by `+`${channel.owner_id}`+` in the category `+channel.parent_id);
    });
```

I want to make a basic log section for my bot, and I am just starting. I want it to be like

```
00:00:00 CREATE >  [Text / Voice] Channel was created by [Creator] under category [category]!
```

I know the exact format isn't implemented into the code, I test a lot of the function before I make it pretty lol. But it comes out like this (using the code I have now)

```
text channel, s, was created by undefined in the category undefined
```

I'm so confused because I like detail so I want to have who created it, when, and also the category! So how would I do that?

Also, would there be a way to send messages and stuff from the console?
Like if I typed this in the console

```
[channel or user] > [the message]
#testchannel > Announcing new video or something idk
```

and have it send to the channel? any help is appreciated!

edit: I forgot to mention that I have the owner_id part in `${var}` format because I was testing to see if that would make it work, but I never switched it back lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `channel.parent.name` would work but there isn't any way to know who created the channel , here's the code -

```js
client.on("channelCreate", function(channel){
    console.log(channel.type+` channel, `+channel.name+`,`+` in the category `+channel.parent.name);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly! Wait there isn't a way to see who made it? In the discord developer docs there is .owner_id so what would that be?

Comment: No there's isn't any way to see who made the channel

Comment: Also is there a way to have the Timestamp of it? or does that not work either

Comment: channel.createdTimestamp

Comment: @StarsTracker there is actually a way to see who made the channel, just fetch the audit logs as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64502583/6901876).

Comment: Yeah if you are trying that make sure to delay using the discord utils, as that takes some time to update

Comment: oh I just saw all of this lol but how would I make the timestamp work UwU

Comment: like what way ?

Comment: oh like it shows up as 1607918627970 when I tested it, but how would I make it format like YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: Use `channel.createdAt` instead of `channel.createdTimestamp`. The former returns a `Date` object which is more formattable than the latter, which returns a long number in milliseconds as you've seen. And then the `Date` object will return a format similar to: `Weekday Month DD YYYY HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: thanks so much it works perfectly now!
the output looks like this now:
23:17:26 CREATE >  text Channel, df, was created
I removed the parent thing because it crashed when I tried to dm the bot lol but it works perfect!

Comment: `if(message.channel.dm)return;` should fix it when someone dm's the bot

Comment: Are you sure about that @StarsTracker? I can't find any documentation for `channel` having a `dm` property. Also, since the error is occurring in this `channelCreate` event and not the `message` event handler, you wouldn't use `message.channel`, just use  `channel`. I think you would do: `if (channel.type == "dm") return;`

Comment: ok I got that was a mistake you can go with above explanation !

Comment: One more question if someone would help,
I installed Ubuntu Bash for Windows, and after that node.js started saying this every startup:
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: Circular symlink detected: "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Application Data" points to "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local"
It says it when I try to run a javascript file
and it makes it so I cannot type into node.js or rs, and to restart, I have to ctrl+c and then redo the startup command! Normally it auto-restarts... What is happening do I need to uninstall bash?

Comment: I have no clue; consider creating an entirely new question for that, because it exceeds the scope of this question and others may be able to better help you with that issue.

Comment: oh lol well I am just gonna uninstall it and see if it fixes itself because I won't use it anyways lol